# Django-Tables2 LinkColumn link doesn't work

Tags: django, django-tables2

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but I've been stuck at this for so long, I had to post the question.

[Link to screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k4s90zx2rl3wwl/Screenshot%202014-07-19%2022.38.51.png)

1. When I click on the link generated in LinkColumn of django-tables2, it redirects back to the same page. Here's my code:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'admin', views.admin, name='admin'),
    url(r'admin/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.bug_edit, name='bug_edit'),
    url(r'admin/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.bug_delete, name='bug_delete'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def bug_edit(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is an edit page!')

def bug_delete(request):
    return HttpResponse('This is a delete page!')
```

forms.py:

```
class SimpleTable(tables.Table):
    edit_link = tables.LinkColumn('bug_edit', args=[A('pk')], 
                verbose_name='Edit', accessor='pk',      attrs={'class':'edit_link'})
    delete_link = tables.LinkColumn('bug_delete', args=[A('pk')], 
                verbose_name='Delete Bug', accessor='pk', attrs={'class':'delete_link'})
    class Meta:
        attrs = {'class' : 'paleblue'}
        model = BugModel
```

I don't see the HttpResponse on clicking the links, as I should.

Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is with views, just check the urls

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you think the problem is? When I click on the link, the URL changes, but it still shows the same table page.

Comment: first, remove slash from the end of `bug_edit` and `bug_delete` urls and check if the table hyperlink works

Comment: Did that. Still stays on same page, but url changes.

Comment: does '127.0.0.1:8000/admin/edit/1' or '127.0.0.1:8000/admin/delete/1' works?

Comment: No. Look: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dd193dhp82qsmjh/Screenshot%202014-07-22%2011.04.21.png

Comment: Well, according to your urls and views, those link should not show tables. Those should show only a html response.

Comment: I know. That's what's confusing me.

Comment: clear cache, freshly go to the urls `bug_edit` and `bug_delete` without accessing the table page. check what happens

Comment: Same table page appears. Even at the bug_edit and bug_delete urls.

Comment: I guess problem is not with your table, problem is somewhere else, maybe context data.

Comment: Any idea how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your url patterns are missing ^ and $.

Without them, the 'admin' pattern is matching any url with 'admin' in it -- effectively masking the following patterns.

Try using this instead:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/$', views.admin, name='admin'),
    url(r'^admin/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.bug_edit, name='bug_edit'),
    url(r'^admin/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.bug_delete, name='bug_delete'),
)
```