# I literally been stuck in this loop for days. edit/update can't detect the pk of the model?should i submit a ticket?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

the error :

```
.Reverse for 'patient_update' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['patients/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$']?
```

whenever i try calling the url in a template whether in action of a form tag or just a normal anchor.

I made a view where users can edit the patients information and as I'm using a custom user model I had to make a custom update/delete view.The views are working when i enter them manually by the url but when i put a link reference to them by an anchor tag i get an error that it can't access the pk,I tried following many answers here and vids on YT but the error is still there

Views.py

```
def PatientUpdateView(request,pk=None):
   patient = get_object_or_404(models.Patient, pk=pk)
   form = forms.PatientForm(request.POST or None ,instance=patient)
   if form.is_valid() :
       patient = form.save(commit=False)
       patient.save()
       messages.success(request,"patient updated!")
       context = {
        'patient': patient,
        'form': form
    }
       return render(request,'patients/patient_edit_form_success.html',context)
   else:
       context = {
        'patient' : patient,
        'form': form,
               }
       return render(request, 'patients/patient_edit_form.html', context)
```

and here's how i call it in an anchor tag

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{% url 'patients:patient_update' patient.pk %}">Open</a>
```

I tried

```
pk = patient.pk
pk = pk
pk={{ patient.pk}}
```

and many other ways of calling it.

urls.py here's the url pattern that i use

```
path('update/<int:pk>', views.PatientUpdateView, name='patient_update'),
```

i tried using a url method in the url pattern

I even tried using a class based view so do you have any idea how i can fix it ?

further information

tables.py

```
class PatientTable(tables.Table):

FirstName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
LastName = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
Telephone_no = tables.Column(linkify=("patients:patient_detail", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
# delete = tables.LinkColumn('patients:patient_delete', args=[A('pk')], attrs={
# 'a': {'class': 'btn'}
# })
# update = tables.LinkColumn('patients:patient_update', args=[A('pk')], attrs={
# 'a': {'class': 'btn'}
# })
edit = TemplateColumn(template_name='patients/edit_btn.html')
# delete = TemplateColumn(template_name='patients/patient_delete.html')

class Meta:
    model = Patient
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-hover'}
    exclude = ("user", "Notes", "Adress")
    template_name = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

and the list view

```
def Patients_list(request):
patients = Patient

table = PatientTable(patients.objects.filter(user=request.user))
RequestConfig(request).configure(table)

return render(request, 'patients/patients_list.html',{
'table' : table
})
```

and in the html file of the list view :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}

{% block content %}


<style>

#content{

margin-left : 18%;
margin-right : 2%;

}

</style>


<div id="content">

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h1> Patients list: </h1>
    <br>

    <a href="{%url 'patients:patient_create'%}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Add Patient</a>
    <br>
    <br>

    {% render_table table %}


    {% else %}

      <h2>please login</h2>

    {% endif %}

  {% endblock %}

</div>
```

patient edit_form.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

#content{

margin-top: 100px;
margin-left : 18%;
margin-right : 2%;

}
{% block content %}

<div id="content">

         <h2>Add Patient</h2>
            <form method="POST" >

                {% csrf_token %}
                 {{ form|crispy }}

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
                                <p></p>
            </form>
</div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: You need to show the view that renders the template that link is on, not the one it goes to.

Comment: it's just a Table view with django-tables2 and a TemplateColumn refering to this button with a template_name attribute.

Comment: @AMMARRADY can you show the `views` and `template` that renders the `anchor tag`.

Comment: i edited it in the post.

Comment: Can you show the full template, not just the anchor tag?

Comment: We need to know how you are getting `patient` from the table.

Comment: I edited it in the post.

Comment: That's not the right template. Where is the link to `patient_update`? That's what we need to see, in context. Maybe it is in patients/edit_btn.html?

Comment: sorry got confused

Comment: Sigh that is still not it. *Show the full template that contains the failing url tag*.

Comment: the template of the button is just the button. as I wanted to add a button and I must refer to a template so if i refered the whole update_form.html template it will be rendered inside the table so i just referred a simple link button.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the `accessor` parameter. Put the following in your `PatientTable` class (assuming you are using pk as keyword argument in your urls):

```
update = tables.Column(accessor='pk', linkify=("patients:patient_update", {"pk": tables.A("pk")}))
```

If you want to change how it is rendered, you can write a function, for example:

```
def render_update(self, record):
    return record.first_name # or any other patient attribute or anything else
```

Comment: Thanks, it really helped alot but now the it shows in this column just the pk value so how to change that to a button or at least a word like edit/update. and why i couldn't reference the patient update in just a button ?

Comment: could you give more information about the second example or how to do it with showing buttons ?
there's this example :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415175/how-to-put-submit-buttons-for-every-record-in-django-tables-2

but how i should do it in my case ? it uses the your second example.

Answer (score 0):

I used this in my tables.py and it worked:

```
 edit = tables.LinkColumn('patients:patient_update',text='Edit', args=[A('pk')], attrs={
    'a': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}
    })
```